# I have a strange but simple issue with array in javascript and node js?

Tags: javascript

very simple question that waste my time for several hours: I just try to push data to an array which  exists in my schema but when I use the `.push` I got error that 'can not read property push of undefined' here is my very simple code:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/new_try1");

var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    number: Number,
    name: String
});

var Product = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);

var orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    number: Number,
    name: String,
    products: [productSchema]
});

var Order = mongoose.model("Order", orderSchema);

var newOrder = new Order({
    number: "123",
    name: "jane"
});


newOrder.save(function (err, order) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(order);
    }
});
Order.find({
    name: 'jane'
}, function (err, order) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log(order);// I can see the products array in cmd
        console.log(order.products);// I got undefined here!!!!!????
        order.products.push({// here I got error can not read of un....
            number:456,
            name:'carret'
        });
        order.save(function(err,found){
            if (err){
            console.log(err);   
            }else{
                console.log(found);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

when run the server I got this in cmd for order:

```
[{_id:357636shgs65dh5sd4h65d,
number:'123',
name:'jane',
__v:0,
products:[] }]
```

now why order.product is undefined when I can see it here?

Comment: isnt the return of *find* an array? order[0].products

Comment: your output suggests `order` is an array, so you need to use `order[0].products` maybe!?

Comment: I am sure the syntax is right because I already use it in another project but the strange is that the same syntax doesn't work in another project!?

Comment: definitely you missing array index of product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it simple, it looks like order is this:

```
var order=[
       {_id:357636shgs65dh5sd4h65d,
           number:'123',
           name:'jane',
           __v:0,
           products:[] 
        }];
```

As you can see its an *Array* not an *Object*. So you first need to get the Object of the Array:

```
order //the array
  [0] //the object
  .products //the product array
  .push()//should work now
```

*collection.find* returns a cursor to a collection, wich needs to be *iterated* (= Arraylike)
so you may want to use
*collection.findOne* wich returns just one element, making your code work.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/

```
Order.findOne({
  name: 'jane'
}, function (err, order) {
   order.push("data");
});
```

Comment: with order[0].products.push i didn't get any error but nothing added to my array!!

Comment: thank you dear Jonas using .findOne instead of .find solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your order is an array. So somethiing like this should work:

```
Order.find({
    name: 'jane'
}, function (err, order) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log(order);// I can see the products
        console.log(order[0].products);
        order[0].products.push({
            number:456,
            name:'carret'
        });
        order.save(function(err,found){
            if (err){
            console.log(err);   
            }else{
                console.log(found);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Note: Im not sure on your use case. But it looks like you could retreive multiple orders back from your db so you'll probably want to loop over the orders returned for processing as well

Comment: with order[0].products.push i didn't get any error but nothing added to my array!!